# Perform multiple actions depending on the If .Found = True result

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'd like to know how to perform few actions all of them depending on `If .Found = True` result??
In the macro snippet presented below after `If .Found = True` there is only one action performed: 
`If .Found = True Then mySheet.Cells(x, 5) = mySheet.Range("AD17")`

And I need to write 4 different lines, that I want to execute `If .Found = True`.

```
     If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(mySheet.Range("A12:D15")) = 2 And _
              mySheet.Range("E12") = "????" And _
              mySheet.Range("H12") = "k" Then
                rng.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=endPos
                  With rng.Find
                   .Text = arr(0) & " " & arr(wrdCount1 - 1) & " oświadcza ponadto, że jest wdową."
                   .MatchWildcards = False
                   .MatchCase = False
                   .Forward = True
                   .Execute
                     If .Found = True Then mySheet.Cells(x, 5) = mySheet.Range("AD17")   
                                 'how to insert more actions after IF .Found here without repeating If statement;
                 End With
     ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(mySheet.Range("A12:D15")) = 2 And _
           mySheet.Range("E12") = "????" And _
           mySheet.Range("H12") = "m" Then
               rng.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=endPos
               With rng.Find
                  .Text = arr(0) & " " & arr(wrdCount1 - 1) & " oświadcza ponadto, że jest wdowcem."
                  .MatchWildcards = False
                  .MatchCase = False
                  .Forward = True
                  .Execute
                   If .Found = True Then
                       mySheet.Cells(x, 5) = mySheet.Range("AD18")
                   Else
                       rng.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=endPos
                       With rng.Find
                           .Text = "a przedmiotowego nabycia dokona do majątku osobistego za pieniądze pochodzące z jego majątku osobistego,"
                           .MatchWildcards = False
                           .MatchCase = False
                           .Forward = True
                           .Execute
                       If .Found = True Then mySheet.Cells(x, 6) = mySheet.Range("AE14")  
                                   'how to insert more actions after IF .Found here without repeating If statement;
                       End With
                   End If
             End With
     End If
```

What I need to do is to fill 3 or 4 different cells depending on the `If .Found = True` result without repeating `If .Found = True Then` in every line.

I'm looking for some elegant code.

```
     If .Found = True Then mySheet.Cells(x, 6) = mySheet.Range("AE14") And _
                       mySheet.Cells(x, 7) = "red" And _
                       mySheet.Cells(x, 8) = "100 000" And _
                       mySheet.Cells(x, 10) = mySheet.Range("AE25") * 0,23
```

Comment: everything after the "then" needs to go on the next line and you'll need an end if to end the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as that should work

```
If .Found = True Then 
          mySheet.Cells(x, 6) = mySheet.Range("AE14") 
          mySheet.Cells(x, 7) = "red" 
          mySheet.Cells(x, 8) = "100 000" 
          mySheet.Cells(x, 10) = mySheet.Range("AE25") * 0,23
End if
```